# Does part of a sentence starting with "For why else" need question mark?

Tags: questions, punctuation

> Death must be an evil — and the gods agree; **for why else** would they
>   live for ever **?**

Source: Sappho (c. 600 B.C.). Poetarum Lesbiorum Fragmenta, ed. Edgar Lobel and Denys Page. Oxford: Clarendon Press, 1955, no. 201.

> Alan likes Juli, **for why else** should he buy her all those presents **?**

Do the above sentences need question mark or point at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, by "indirect question" you mean a ["rhetorical question"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/rhetorical-question), then you have provided your own answer.  Rhetorical questions may or may not end with a question mark -- it's entirely personal preference.

Rhetorical questions can be phrased in exactly the same way as a direct question.  I'm not sure why you think there is some rule to define the difference.  Perhaps this is something you have been incorrectly taught, otherwise, **why else would you believe it to be true ./?**

Now, my *personal preference* would be to end that last sentence with a question mark.  But there is nothing wrong with instead ending it with a period.

Alternately I could have written it without using "would":

> why else **do** you believe it to be true?

and it would still have been a rhetorical question.

It's a little more complicated when the rhetorical question appears in the middle of the sentence.  In general, end with a question mark if you want the *entire sentence* to be perceived as a question (rhetorical or nor).  Otherwise end with a period.

Here's a clumsy pair of examples.

> You might ask, why would we end a rhetorical question with a period, when it's not a real inquiry that expects a response?
>
> You might ask, why would we end a rhetorical question with a period, but the answer is simply that it's not a real inquiry that expects a response.

The second sentence is fine as written, but my personal style is to set off the question with quotation marks, and turn it into a direct question.

> You might ask, "Why would we end a rhetorical question with a period?" but the answer is simply that it's not a real inquiry that expects a response.